# How to validate JWT token if there is two access tokens?

Tags: jwt

I'm concerned about how to validate access tokens. 
For example. If User1 has access_token and refresh_token. And User2 hijacked login and password of User1 and enter to example.org. How to recognize that tokens of User1 is invalid

Answer (score 0):

JWT validation includes JWT should be well formed, validating signature and validation of standard claims like exp, aud and scopes. We can avoid credentials/session hijacking using proper techniques like mutual SSL between client and application server, If its just sharing of credentials to another user then it is difficult to avoid, In that case you have opt for 2nd factor authentication mechanisms, or may be a step up authentication process.